# Cannot access class from another class c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to access public partial class ChooseExercises : Window from public partial class YourProgress : Window, but it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'GymCheckList.YourProgress' to type 'GymCheckList.ChooseExercises'.'
```

The way I'm trying to access it is:

```
namespace GymCheckList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for YourProgress.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class YourProgress : Window
    {
        public YourProgress()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void TabThursday_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChooseExercises ce = (ChooseExercises)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    var lol = ce;
}
```

If I use ChooseExerises ce = new ChooseExercises(); it gives me empty ce incstance. What may cause the exception?
Thanks!

Edit

In ChooseExeprises class I used similar code to access the MainWindow class and it works fine:

```
namespace GymCheckList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ChooseExercises.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ChooseExercises : Window
    {
        public ChooseExercises()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private List<string> data = new List<string>();
        public void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow kek = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Comment: do they have the same namespace? or is the namespace imported?

Comment: " What may cause the exception" -> Application.Current.MainWindow is not of type ChooseExercises. Set a breakpoint and inspect the actual type.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Yes, they have the same namespace..

Comment: @PeterBons very heplful, good guy.

Comment: You are type casting in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your main window is a `YourProgress` but you could try to get a reference to the `ChooseExercises` window using the `Application.Current.Windows` collection:

```
private void TabThursday_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChooseExercises ce = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ChooseExercises>().FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
But why couldn't I get it using:
ChooseExercises ce = (ChooseExercises)Application.Current.MainWindow; ?

Comment: Because Application.Current.MainWindow doesn't return a ChooseExercises window. Please read my answer again and ask a new question if you have another issue.